# Multiple status bar notifications created in a row produce only one sound alert

Tags: android, notifications

I'm writing a program that monitors several different events and creates status bar notifications when certain conditions are met. The idea is that based on the specific condition there are different notification sounds played, so that the user would know what is happening without having to look at the phone. All notifications are created with different id's (right now random numbers are used, though I may change that later) so they do not override one another. All show up in a status bar and play their notification sounds appropriately.

So far so good, but here is a problem. The program main loop in a service sleeps for set amount of time, then wakes up and checks all conditions, creating necessary notifications. It often boils out to having to create two or more notifications in a row. Here comes the problem, only the sound alert of the last notification that is popped up is being played. So the user will never know there was more than one notification about different events just from the sound.

Any way this can be remedied? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
After reading some comments and messing around a bit more, it looks like I know WHY this is happening, but not HOW TO FIX it. So the question is still open as of this update. When two notifications popped up as the phone pretty busy (read slow to respond), I could hear the beginning of first sound that was then taken over by the second one. So it looks like the system is honestly trying to play the first sound, but when second notification comes up it simply puts the new sound up cancelling the first playback... So I guess I need to try and find out if there's a way to tell the system to play them in sequence, not all at once...

UPDATE2:
For now - added code to make sure there is at least 5 seconds between any two notifications being created, and it does solve the problem. As I mentioned in comments below, I don't think it's the best solution, so while this allows me to continue working on the project, I'm still looking for a better way to do it.

Here's the code that creates a notification:

```
    public void ShowNotification(String Ticker, String Title, String Text,Hero H, Uri Sound, int Icon){
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        CharSequence tickerText = Ticker;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(Icon, tickerText, when);

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;    
        notification.sound=Sound;


        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = Title;
        CharSequence contentText = Text;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AlertActivity.class);


        notificationIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.FROM_NOTIFICATION), true);


        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, rnd.nextInt(), notificationIntent, 0);


        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);




        try{
            mNotificationManager.notify(rnd.nextInt(), notification);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.w("Service", "Notification Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's just a guess but maybe Notifications do that for a purpose, they are not intended to be abused as a soundboard :) Maybe you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html for that

Comment: Thanks, zapl. I'll look into that as a possibility if I can't get the notifications to cooperate. That said, I have seen applications that pop-up multiple notifications in rapid succession and I hear the sounds following one-another in rapid sequence. In that case the same sound twice in a row. Who knows, maybe they are indeed using SoundPool for that...

Comment: Maybe it works with Notifications if you use the right flags (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE ?) or cancel the Notification before you show a new one.

Comment: Don't see any flags that would have effected it in any way. As to cancelling it - I can't do that, because other than sound notification that can be missed, there's also a distinctive icon and a line in pull-down status to make sure user will see it at once (if they missed the sound after all). One thing I was thinking of, is to sleep for 5 seconds between notifications, but I don't think it's fully effective, because for one the user will be annoyed by having a new one every 5 seconds, and second, if the system is busy at the time, it may stack them up in a buffer and still show all at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(yourCondition) 
   notification.sound =  android.net.Uri.parse(sharedPrefs.getString(CommonDefn.PREFERENCE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONG, Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI.toString()));
```

Comment: This is essentially what I do to get the Sound parameter, which is passed to the function quoted in my question. I get teh sound allright. The problem is - when I shoot out two notifications in a row (with different sounds) only the sound of last one is heard. After messing a bit, I think I know why: the later sound just overrides the former. Goind to update the question with this.

Comment: oh, change your PendingIntent as:  int num = random.nextInt();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
      context, num, intent,
      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: Tried it just now. No candy. You are suggesting to add FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, which won't do much when we use a random id, since system will treat each notification as unique one (unless two identical random numbers are generated, in which case this would be helpful). The sound from second notification still overrides the first one. A 5 second pause between launching notifications does do the trick as I described in update to the question. But I'm not very happy with that solution...

Comment: try: public static void sound(Context context)
 {
  MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  try
  {
   mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, RingtoneManager
     .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
   AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
     .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0)
   {
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
   }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   
  }

 }

Comment: Ok, tried this one too. I guess the result is a bit better, but.... Used your function with my Sound variable instead of default, while not assigning any sound to notification itself. The second sound begins playing milliseconds after the first one and mixes together with the first. So I could hear both of them playing pretty much at the same time. I guess a user with musical hearing may be able to hear them both play, but in my ideal world I'd rather them play sequentially, not simultaneously.